# UIBarButtonItem with custom UIButton is invisible on iOS <= 10

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I need to create a "burger menu" button for my app on my navigationController's left side but since the NavCon is transparent I need to have a shadow on my icon.

Thus I've created a custom UIButton with an image, a drop shadow and the added it as a custom view on a UIBarButtonItem as follows:

```
let menuButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSideMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
menuButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu_white"), for: .normal)
menuButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
menuButton.layer.masksToBounds = false
menuButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
menuButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
menuButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5
menuButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButton)
```

The code above works perfectly fine on iOS 11, but when I tested my app on ios 9 and 10 (both simulators and real devices) the menu icon is invisible. It is clickable and works as expected, but there is no visible icon.

In the View Hierarchy Debugger I can see a UIButton with 0 width and height, while in ios 11 I can see the normal UIButtonBarStackview with the embedded UIButton.

Any ideas on how to fix this and why this is happening? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please mention the button frame

```
 let menuButton =  UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 40))
```

It may helps to you thank you

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick. I've forgotten to set the buttons frame so it was (0,0,0,0). I think that ios 11 takes care of setting the frame itself, but the older versions do not. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just call menuButton.sizeToFit() and it will work.

Comment: Haven't actually tested it, but it should work. The logic is the same, setting the button's frame. Thanks!